# Elm Html and view : Model -> Html Msg

Tags: html, elm

I'm brand new to Elm and I'm struggling to see what is wrong here..

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model = div [] [ button [ onClick NewStrategy ] [ text "-" ] ]
```

complains that..

```
The type annotation for `view` says it always returns:

    Html (Msg)

But the returned value (shown above) is a:

    Html (String -> Msg)
```

It looks no different to http://elm-lang.org/examples/buttons to me. One div with a button inside with an onClick and some text.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You hadn't listed the source code for `Msg` but the error you've listed seems to indicate that the `NewStrategy` constructor takes a single string parameter. If you gave it a string value, it should work.

Example:

```
view model = div [] [ button [ onClick (NewStrategy "submit") ] [ text "submit" ] ]
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense.